# how to pass list to parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I am trying to use parallel in following script

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a ephemeral_list
for mount in $(lsblk | grep ^x | awk '{ print $1 }')
do
   if ! mount | grep $mount >/dev/null; then
      ephemeral_list+=($mount)
   fi
done

for i in "${!ephemeral_list[@]}"
do
  printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${ephemeral_list[$i]}"
  [ -d /mnt/ephemeral$i ] || mkdir /mnt/ephemeral$i
  mkfs.ext4 -E nodiscard /dev/${ephemeral_list[$i]} &&  mount /dev/${ephemeral_list[$i]} /mnt/ephemeral$i &
done
```

I want to run "mkfs.ext4 -E nodiscard /dev/${ephemeral_list[$i]} &&  mount /dev/${ephemeral_list[$i]} /mnt/ephemeral$i &" command on each cpu here

any help ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function. Call that.

```
mymkfs() {
  printf "%s\t%s\n" "$1" "$2"
  [ -d /mnt/ephemeral$1 ] || mkdir /mnt/ephemeral$1
  mkfs.ext4 -E nodiscard /dev/"$2" &&  mount /dev/"$2" /mnt/ephemeral$1
}
export -f mymkfs

parallel mymkfs {#} {} ::: "${ephemeral_list[@]}"
```